# Modify test after string in multiple files

Tags: sed

Think I should use `sed`, but can't get it down correctly.

I have a folder full of text files.
They're all constructed the same, with a list of variables, e.g.

```
NAME=John
AGE=30
CODE=xyz
```

I need to look at all files, and modify the value of a variable, like CODE, to something.
So, file1.txt - change `CODE=xyz` to `CODE=123`
file2.txt - change `CODE=foo` to `CODE=123`

What I change it TO will be the same for all files.

Is `sed` the best for this?

Comment: Hard returns between each variable.
NAME=John

AGE=30

CODE=xyz

Answer (score 1):

This should be able to change those values:

```bsh
find /path/to/foler/ -type f -exec sed 's/CODE=.../CODE=123/' {} \;
```

Running the above code will not change anything but lets you see what gets changed. To get it to chanage those values add the `-i` flag:

```bsh
find /path/to/folder/ -type f -exec sed -i 's/CODE=.../CODE=123/' {} \;
```

Backups are also possible but with the kind of size, your talking about this might not be a good idea.

Information:

- `...`: represents just three letters or characters, so `.` will be for one
- `-type f`: we are looking for files only
- `-i`: change the values in-place

Comment: find /home/user/folder/configs/ -type f -exec sed -i 's/currency=.../currency=m/g' {} \;

doesn't seem to do anything :(

Comment: GOT IT ... = number of chars, so for a single character change, us one .

Comment: Yes sir you guessed right sorry I didn't explain that

Comment: In addition we could use `.*$` if we want to match all (`*`) characters (`.`) to the end (`$`) of the line. Also I think we do not need the `g` flag here.

Comment: Yes I noticed with the `g` flag, let me update that!